# Unable to display in right format - PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

My Controller Function

```
public function fetchAllCategory() {
    $resultlist = $this->BlogModel->fetchData('*', 'blogcategory', array());
    $result = array();
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($resultlist as $key => $value) {
        $result['data'][] = array(
          $i++,
          $value['Category'],
          '<a class="btn btn-info" href="#" title="Edit Category" onClick="editCategory("' . $value['Category'] . '")"><i class = "fas fa-edit"></i></a> '
          . '<a class = "btn btn-danger" href = "' . base_url('Blog/deleteCategory/') . $value['catId'] . '" onClick = "return confirm(\'are you sure you want to delete?\');"><center><i class = "fa fa-trash-alt"></i></center></a>'
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    //' . base_url('Blog/editCategory/') . $value['catId'] . '
}
```

My View (Inspect Element )

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="#" title="Edit Category" onclick="editCategory(" business")"=""><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-edit fa-w-18" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="edit" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M402.6 83.2l90.2 90.2c3.8 3.8 3.8 10 0 13.8L274.4 405.6l-92.8 10.3c-12.4 1.4-22.9-9.1-21.5-21.5l10.3-92.8L388.8 83.2c3.8-3.8 10-3.8 13.8 0zm162-22.9l-48.8-48.8c-15.2-15.2-39.9-15.2-55.2 0l-35.4 35.4c-3.8 3.8-3.8 10 0 13.8l90.2 90.2c3.8 3.8 10 3.8 13.8 0l35.4-35.4c15.2-15.3 15.2-40 0-55.2zM384 346.2V448H64V128h229.8c3.2 0 6.2-1.3 8.5-3.5l40-40c7.6-7.6 2.2-20.5-8.5-20.5H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V306.2c0-10.7-12.9-16-20.5-8.5l-40 40c-2.2 2.3-3.5 5.3-3.5 8.5z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Font Awesome fontawesome.com --></a>
```

I want to perform onClick functionality using Anchor tab, But I am facing issues.
As below screen If I click any Category edit button then It will fill the value in left text box.

for the Last Category "16" I am not getting any issue but when I am failed with any string.
[image: Dashboard]

My JavaScript Code

```
function editCategory($id) {
        document.getElementById("category").value = $id;
        console.log($id)
    }
```

Comment: I did not understand your problem

Comment: Hi Giacomo, 

I want, If I click on Edit Button then the Blog Category will fill in left Textbox.

I want to change onclick="editCategory(" business")"=""

into onclick="editCategory('business')

Comment: What you mean with this "but when I am failed with any string"?

Comment: Means If I want to edit 16 then It will fill the left text box with value 16 but when I try with Tech, Business or Sports then I am not able to fill the value.
I use Inspect element and found this

onclick="editCategory(" tech")"=""

Now I want to change it to 
onclick="editCategory('tech')"

Comment: you use jQuery?

Comment: Could you please provide me solution? because I tried too much but I didn't found any solution to fix this issue.

Comment: @B. Dontos have you solved your problem or not??

Comment: I got the solution